# If A is a Normal. Prove that the column space of A equals to the column space of A*

Tags: matrices

Q: Given a Normal matrix $A \in M_{n}^{\mathrm{c}}$. Prove that the column space of A equals to the column space of A*.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is normal then for any vector $v$ we have

$$\lVert A v\rVert^2 = \langle Av, Av\rangle = \langle A^*v, A^*v\rangle = \lVert A^*v\rVert^2.$$

This shows $\ker A = \ker A^*$. Now use the fact that $\ker A = (\text{im} A^*)^{\perp}$ and $\ker A^* = (\text{im} A)^{\perp}$.